# Paypal SDK sandbox mode return status "Created"

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have integrated Paypal in my android app, user can pay by either Paypal or card.
Card Payment is working correctly but when paying through Paypal returns status "created" instead of "approved".

Below is response from Paypal -

```
{
"client": {
    "environment": "sandbox",
    "paypal_sdk_version": "x.xx.x",
    "platform": "Android",
    "product_name": "PayPal-Android-SDK"
},
"response": {
    "create_time": "2016-05-23T10:51:47Z",
    "id": "PAY-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "intent": "sale",
    "state": "created"
},
"response_type": "payment"
```

}

Why it is not returning status to approved. 
What is wrong in my code.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

For Sandbox environment, You need to use a credit card that is registered under the sandbox personal account. Check the "Profile" of the PayPal sandbox personal account and go to the "Funding" tab for the test credit card. This will give you a "approved" result instead of "created".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are created the Merchant account as Business account in your sandbox, but we need to create Business-Pro account in sandbox.

I got solved the issue by created like that.